# What is the difference between "Linkable" and "Traceable" Ring Signatures?

Tags: public-key, symmetric, anonymity

In particular, both papers on [Traceable Ring Signatures](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/790/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-540-71677-8_13.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2F978-3-540-71677-8_13&token2=exp=1473342903~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F790%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252F978-3-540-71677-8_13.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252F978-3-540-71677-8_13*~hmac=b5857e98cb7d4d49aa7297fee23b8904b0cea07122b5f5e14d1c59fe2a51ec10) and [Linkable Ring Signatures](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/027.pdf) propose they are fit for the creation of ballots. The [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature) on Ring Signatures, though, suggests Linkable Ring Signatures can't be used for that purpose. Which is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Wikipedia Article on Ring Signatures, though, suggests Linkable Ring Signatures can't be used for that purpose.

The Wikipedia article doesn't say or imply that. It lists possible applications:

- Linkable Ring Signatures: "... One of the possible applications can be an offline e-cash system."
- Tracable Ring Signatures: "... An e-voting system can be implemented using this protocol."

First, neither claims explicitly that you can create ballots with it, which is only a part of an e-voting system. And then if something is listed for one of them, it doesn't mean that you can create that *only* with this one.

And then, you have the wrong source for link signatures. Liu and Wong also wrote *Linkable ring signatures: Security models and new schemes* just one year later, which builds upon your linked paper but refines it. (although I can't find a publicly available version atm)